# How to Run a Form Both Visibly and Invisibly based on a parameter with C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form that is run as a scheduled task.  When it is run, nothing shows up, the program executes.  I would also like the option of showing the form and manually executing the program with the different options that are available on the main form.

So, using parameters, I am able to run this and it works fine as a scheduled task.  As a form, however, I am unable to get the form to show.

Here is my code:

```
  ******* MAIN PROGRAM
  static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length > 0)
        { 
            Application.Run(new FileProcessor(true));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new FileProcessor(false));
        }
    }

  ******* INSIDE THE FORM

    bool RunOnSchedule = true;

    private bool setCore;
    public FileProcessor(bool automatic = true)
    {
        RunOnSchedule = automatic;
        if (RunOnSchedule)
        {
            setCore = true;
            SetVisibleCore(false);
        }
        else
        {
          SetVisibleCore(true);
        }   
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!RunOnSchedule)
        {
            btnProcess.Visible = false;
        }

        if (RunOnSchedule)
        {
            object sender = new object();
            EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
            FileProcessor_Load(sender, e);
            GetDefaultFiles();
            BtnProcess_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
    {
        base.SetVisibleCore(setCore ? value : setCore);
    }
```

If it doesn't run as a scheduled task, the form won't show up.  I have tried using ShowDialog() instead of .Run() but it still doesn't work.

Any thoughts, ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered centralizing/modulating the processing logic in a global function accessible from either the form instance or the Main function?  I believe that the Application.Run(form) method automatically sets the form as visible, thus overriding any other setting of that property.  You could then call the global function with default parameters directly from the Main function OR instantiate your form (using Application.Run(form)) and call the same global function from the event handler for your button.

Comment: I did consider that and, now that you say it, it seems like the best practice approach.  Thank you!